# How to auto-create a view page from an action on visual studio 2019 mac

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've seen a few times that there is an option (On right click on IActionResult) to auto-create a view page from an action.

Do I need to install more packages to do so?

[image]

Comment: I code with VSCode on MacOS. However Visual Studio for Mac has fewer features than the version for Windows.